# How do I stop bash from adding ^@ before each letter in vim

Tags: bash, csv, vim

A problem occured for no reason, in a code that worked previously.

There is some data in myfile.csv

```
MP 0,20,60,200,60,95,100,1,20,50,30,20,20,250,115,200,0,8,85,150,465817

MP 1,17.89,60,200,60,93.945,100,1,20,50,30,20,20,250,115,200,0,10,85,150,465927

MP 2,16.33,60,200,60,93.16,100,1,20,50,30,20,20,250,115,200,0,12,85,150,464987

MP 3,15.12,60,200,60,92.56,100,1,20,50,30,20,20,250,115,200,0,14,85,150,463440

...
```

I extracted the last 25 lines of my files

```
tail -n 25 myfile.csv > test1.txt
```

When I do

```
cat test1.txt

...
MP 16,20,60,200,60,95,100,1,20,120,30,20,20,250,115,200,0,8,85,150,529469
MP 17,20,60,200,60,95,100,1,20,130,30,20,20,250,115,200,0,8,85,150,534335
```

no problem... but i want to go in a text editor, every letters is preceded by ^@ :

```
vim test1.txt

^@M^@P^@ ^@0^@,^@2^@0^@,^@6^@0^@,^@2^@0^@0^@,^@6^@0^@,^@9^@5^@,^@1^@0^@0^@,^@1^@,^@2^@0^@,^@5^@0^@,^@3^@0^@,^@2^@0^@,^@2^@0^@,^@2^@5^@0^@,^@1^@1^@5^@,^@2^@0^@0^@,^@0^@,^@8^@,^@8^@5^@,^@1^@5^@0^@,^@4^@6^@5^@8^@1^@7^@
```

and the problem is a want to make a pattern search ( the first word of the line ) that doesn't seem to work because of that

```
home > awk '/MP 0/{print}' test1.txt
home >
```

Moreover i would like to put a parameter in my awk :

```
home > cat mp
0
home > awk "/MP `cat mp`,/{print}" test1.txt
home >
```

Do you know where does this error comes from ?

thank you

### ***EDIT***

The .csv file was saved in Excel 2007 as a "CSV (DOS)"

By saving it as a "CSV" it works => encoding is different

Otherwise, when opening it in vim, do :e ++enc=utf16 to reload the file with the UTF-16 encoding, then (assuming the nullbytes disappeared) do :set fenc=utf-8 and save the file.  ( thank you @L3viathan for this answer )

Comment: Is your input file a UTF-16 encoded file without BOM?

Comment: Quit copying Windoze files and attempting to open them in vim??? To get rid of the DOS line endings in `vim`, use `:%s/[ctrlkey+v and ctrl-key+M]//g` That is, press `:` then write `%s/` now the 2 control sequences, then `//g` and the final substitution will look like `:%s/^V^M//g` then just press return.

Comment: @L3viathan i am not familiar with encodings, do you know how and where can i check it ?

Comment: try following, 

cat yourFile.txt |tr -d '\a\b\r' >new

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the command   :%s/[ctrlkey+v and ctrl-key+M]//g  worked thank you :). 

I think the error comes from the .csv file that was saved in excel with the option " CSV (DOS) " instead of  "CSV" . when i tried with "CSV" there where no problem.

Comment: Yep, that will do it as well `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your encoding is messed up. Your file was probably saved with the UTF-16 encoding, but for some reason the Byte-Order Mark (`0xFEFF`) is missing.

After you opened it in vim, do `:e ++enc=utf16` to reload the file with the UTF-16 encoding, then (assuming the nullbytes disappeared) do `:set fenc=utf-8` and save the file.

Comment: `vim +'e ++enc=utf16 | set fenc=utf-8 | x' input` should do the trick without being interactive.

Comment: It works indeed :) and thanks to all your comment i found the problem : the .csv file was saved in excel as a "CSV ( DOS )"  instead of a CSV. I guess the encoding is different for the two format. Thank you both @andlrc and L3viathan